# Create unique 8 character user id using first and last name, compare existing user id's in MySQL table, insert when unique

Tags: php, mysql, compare, unique

I would like to create a unique 8 character userid using the values contained in $first_name and $last_name. 1st digit will be a number between 1 and 9. Second digit will be the user's first initial of their first name. last 6 digits will be the first six digits of their last name. All lower case.

ex:

```
$first_name = "Jack";
$last_name = "Exampleman";

$counter = 1;
$userid = $counter.strtolower(substr($first_name, 0, 1)).strtolower(substr($last_name, 0, 6));
```

produces: 1jexampl

This works great for creating a SINGLE $userid. However, I need to check against a MySQL table to see if it is unique. If it does not exist, insert. If it does exist add 1 to counter, then check to see if the new modified $userid exists. Repeat the check and adding to the counter (to a maximum $counter value of 8).

WHAT IS THE LOGIC to iterate the MySQL check, until the proposed $userid is confirmed unique? I have something like:

```
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT userid FROM staff2 WHERE userid = '$userid'";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $counter ++;
        $userid = $counter.strtolower(substr($first_name, 0, 1)).strtolower(substr($last_name, 0, 6));
}
$connect->query("INSERT INTO staff2 (userid, first_name, last_name) VALUES('$userid', '$first_name', '$last_name')");
```

Comment: I'm sure you have heard of `recursion` right? this is a perfect example where you can use a recursive function.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm new to some of this.

Comment: You mean *characters*, not *digits*. Digits are 0-9. Also @cmorrissey why recursive function when a simple loop will do and be a lot easier to handle?

Comment: Yes Sami. I changed character to digit in the title originally, to make the title shorter. Thanks for catching this. I've changed it back, to be more clear.

Comment: Don't forget this will be subject to race conditions.  Surround the whole thing in a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use recursion to solve as follows:

```
    //initial running of the function:
userExists($userid, $connect,  $counter, $first_name, $last_name);

function userExists($userid, $connect,  $counter, $first_name, $last_name) {

    // someone with the same userid exists in the database.
$sql = "SELECT userid FROM staff2 WHERE userid = '$userid'";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print "It appears that $userid exists!<P>";

        $counter ++;
        //print "The new counter value should be one more than above, it's now: $counter. <br> The userid at this point is still: $userid <P>";
        $userid = $counter.strtolower(substr($first_name, 0, 1)).strtolower(substr($last_name, 0, 6));
        userExists($userid, $connect2,  $counter, $first_name, $last_name);
        return;

    }

    $connect->query("INSERT INTO staff2 (userid, first_name, last_name) VALUES('$userid', '$first_name', '$last_name')");
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful to others looking to create unique userid's using names :-)

Comment: That code is prone to many vulnerabilities. It also imposes an upper limit on the number of possible users, and with each new user the algorithm becomes slower and slower. Btw. you're not safe from concurrency issues etc. You just planted mines in your nice rose garden. I think that the title should be "how to mine your field and hate yourself".

Comment: Thank you for this feedback N.B.

I certainly welcome a better solution :-)

Comment: I'll gladly provide a better solution if you explain why you need this feature at all. It's easy to optimize if the requirement is known. Otherwise.. we can just guess :)

Comment: Sure. We have a large pre-set of staff (about 1000) being populated into a database table (automated via cron job), then a smaller sub-set of non-core staff which needs to be added to the same table individually (about 200 ish). The non-core staff requirement for this project requires an 8 character unique userid, created from their names, which starts with a 1 digit number (so max 9). Single entry person, so concurrency is not too much of a concern at this time.

Comment: Ok, but why do you need this 8 character unique string? People are using that to access something in your app by typing it or remembering it? What's the function of the 8 char unique string that's made out of their user details? Is it even needed? Why can't a number fill that purpose?

Comment: yes, it's being used elsewhere. Also, yes the users will need to remember it, and there are other reasons it needs to be that way.

Comment: Well, sometimes one can't escape oddities :) anyway, I'd change the script to use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of manually checking the existence. You got the algorithm for generating the string. IMO, it's much easier to remember something like `15` or `25` instead of `1_murphy_jones` etc. but I know you can't change the requirements all the time.